# oracle sql to get all possible combinations in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hello guys I have a small predicatement that has me a bit stumped. I have a table like the following.(This is a sample of my real table. I use this to explain since the original table has sensitive data.)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST01( 
TUID VARCHAR2(50),
FUND VARCHAR2(50),
ORG  VARCHAR2(50));
Insert into TEST01 (TUID,FUND,ORG) values ('9102416AB','1XXXXX','6XXXXX');
Insert into TEST01 (TUID,FUND,ORG) values ('9102416CC','100000','67130');
Insert into TEST01 (TUID,FUND,ORG) values ('955542224','1500XX','67150');
Insert into TEST01 (TUID,FUND,ORG) values ('915522211','1000XX','67XXX');
Insert into TEST01 (TUID,FUND,ORG) values ('566653456','xxxxxx','xxxxx');
Insert into TEST01 (TUID,FUND,ORG) values ('9148859fff','1XXXXXX','X6XXX');
```

table data after insert

```
"TUID"                        "FUND"                        "ORG"                         
"9102416AB"                   "1XXXXX"                      "6XXXXX"                      
"9102416CC"                   "100000"                      "67130"                       
"955542224"                   "1500XX"                      "67150"                       
"915522211"                   "1000XX"                      "67XXX"                       
"566653456"                   "xxxxxx"                      "xxxxx"                       
"9148859fff"                  "1XXXXXX"                     "X6XXX"
```

The "X"'s are wild card elements*( I inherit this and i cannot change the table format)* i would  like to make a query like the following

```
select tuid from test01 where fund= '100000' and org= '67130'
```

however what i really like to do is retrieve any records that have have those segements in them including 'X's

```
in other words the expected output here would be 

"TUID"                        "FUND"                        "ORG"                         
"9102416AB"                   "1XXXXX"                      "6XXXXX"                      
"9102416CC"                   "100000"                      "67130"                       
"915522211"                   "1000XX"                      "67XXX"                       
"566653456"                   "xxxxxx"                      "xxxxx"
```

i have started to write a massive sql statement that would have like 12 like statement in it since i would have to compare the org and fund every possible way.
This is where im headed. but im wondering if there is a better way.

```
select * from test02
where fund = '100000' and org = '67130'
or fund like '1%' and org like '6%'
or fund like '1%' and org like '67%'
or fund like '1%' and org like '671%'
or fund like '1%' and org like '6713%'
or fund like '1%' and org like '67130'
or fund like '10%' and org like '6%'...etc

/*seems like there should be a better way..*/
```

can anyone give me a hand coming up with this sql statement...

by the way notice that

```
 "9148859fff"                  "1XXXXXX"                     "X6XXX"
```

is excluded from the expected resul since the second digit in org is "6" and im looking for anything that looks like "67130"

Comment: Just a note: `fund like '1%' and org like '6%'` supersedes all other conditions.

Comment: Can you have `X7130` and if so, what should be done about it? Or `67X30`?

Comment: @PM yes you can have "X7130" and in that case it needs to be included and also you can have 67x30 and it needs to also be included inthe query thought very unlikely because the wild cards work like this "XXXXX","1XXXX","10XXXXX","100XXX" etc. there will not be any open spaces in between the characters hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Should `6XXXXX` really match, since it has more characters than your target `67130`?

Comment: it should not i apologize that was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) function to replace `x` with wildcard character `_` and then use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test01
WHERE '100000' LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(fund, 'x', '_'), 'X', '_')
  AND  '67130' LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(org,  'x', '_'), 'X', '_') ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4cf5/2)**

Comment: thank you this is flexible applicable and elegant. I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to match both "`X`" and "`x`":

```
SELECT *
FROM Test01 t1
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t1.fund, '^[Xx1][Xx0][Xx0][Xx0][Xx0][X0x]$')  AND  
      REGEXP_LIKE(t1.org, '^[Xx6][Xx7][Xx1][Xx3][Xx0]$') 
;
```

My regular expressions control the total number of characters in each field: **6** in `fund` and **5** in `org`.

Here's [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5647a/9).

Comment: this works but im limited to "67130" i was trying to get a query where i can change the values. nevertheless very cool query.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
Select * from test01 t   
    where ((t.fund like ('1%') or t.fund like ('X%'))   
    and (t.org like ('6%') or t.org like ('X%'))   
    and t.org not Like('%6%')
```

Comment: You logic will match (for example) `19999` and `650000` among many others.